# Uniqueness of finite measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two finite measure defined on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying that $\mu[0,x)+1/2\mu(x)= \nu[0,x)+1/2\nu(x)$ for any $x\geq 0$. My question is can we conclude that these two measure are equal? Or can we construct two measure that are not equal such as some kinds of dirac measure?

Comment: Do you know what $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to y} \mu(x)$ equals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same. The reason is that a finite measure may have only countable many atoms. In particular, there is a dense set in $[0,\infty)$ , say $D$, such that for any  $d\in D$ we have $\mu([0,d)) = \nu([0,d))$. So, they have to agree on "closed/open" intervals, i.e.  $\mu([d_1,d_2)) = \nu([d_1,d_2))$. Then, since any open interval $(a,b)$ can be written as a sum of sets of the form $[d_1,d_2)$ where $d_1,d_2 \in D$ the measures are the same on any open interval. Lastly, since measurable sets are generated by open intervals they are the same on any measurable sets.

Comment: Thanks for your help! (how stupid i am ! lol. I've found such $D$ but I didn't find out that any open intervals can be represented as such $[d_1,d_2)$)